# Sending byte array of approximately fixed size everytime to another method

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, byte, bytebuffer

I have a method which takes a parameter which is `Partition` enum. This method will be called by multiple background threads (15 max) around same time period by passing different value of `partition`. Here `dataHoldersByPartition` is a `ImmutableMap` of `Partition` and `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder>`.

```
  private final ImmutableMap<Partition, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder>> dataHoldersByPartition;

  //... some code to populate entry in `dataHoldersByPartition` map

  private void validateAndSend(final Partition partition) {  
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);
    Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = new HashMap<>();
    int totalSize = 0;      
    DataHolder dataHolder;
    while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll())  != null) {      
      byte[] clientKeyBytes = dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      if (clientKeyBytes.length > 255)
        continue;

      byte[] processBytes = dataHolder.getProcessBytes();
      int clientKeyLength = clientKeyBytes.length;
      int processBytesLength = processBytes.length;

      int additionalLength = clientKeyLength + processBytesLength;
      if (totalSize + additionalLength > 50000) {
        Message message = new Message(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder, partition);
        // here size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost
        sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.serialize());
        clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = new HashMap<>();
        totalSize = 0;
      }
      clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.put(clientKeyBytes, processBytes);
      totalSize += additionalLength;
    }
    // calling again with remaining values only if clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder is not empty
    if(!clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.isEmpty()) {
        Message message = new Message(partition, clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);
        // here size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost
        sendToDatabase(message.getAddress(), message.serialize());      
    }
  }
```

And below is my `Message` class:

```
public final class Message {
  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte recordsPartition;
  private final byte replicated;

  public Message(Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder, Partition recordPartition) {
    this.clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder = clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder;
    this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
    this.dataCenter = Utils.CURRENT_LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  // Output of this method should always be less than 50k always
  public byte[] serialize() {
    // 36 + dataSize + 1 + 1 + keyLength + 8 + 2;
    int bufferCapacity = getBufferCapacity(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferCapacity).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    // header layout
    byteBuffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.size())
        .putInt(bufferCapacity).putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin)
        .put(recordsPartition).put(replicated);

    // data layout
    for (Map.Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.entrySet()) {
      byte keyType = 0;
      byte[] key = entry.getKey();
      byte[] value = entry.getValue();
      byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
      short valueLength = (short) value.length;

      ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
      long timestamp = valueLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();

      byteBuffer.put(keyType).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(valueLength)
          .put(value);
    }
    return byteBuffer.array();
  }

  private int getBufferCapacity(Map<byte[], byte[]> clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder) {
    int size = 36;
    for (Entry<byte[], byte[]> entry : clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder.entrySet()) {
      size += 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
      size += entry.getKey().length;
      size += entry.getValue().length;
    }
    return size;
  }

    // getters and to string method here
}
```

Basically, what I have to make sure is whenever the `sendToDatabase` method is called in `validateAndSend` method, size of `message.serialize()` byte array should always be less than 50k at all cost. My `sendToDatabase` method sends byte array coming out from `serialize` method. So for example if I have 60k records in `dataHolders` CLQ then I will send in two chunks in `validateAndSend` method:

- First, I will make a byte array  which is approx less than 50k (meaning byte array coming out from `message.serialize()` is less than 50k) and call `sendToDatabase` method on it.
- Second, I will call `sendToDatabase` method for remianing part.

And to accomplish above things, I was having `totalSize` variable in `validateAndSend` method which is trying to measure 50k size but looks like my approach might not be right and I maybe dropping some records or sending more than 50k everytime I guess?

Looks like my `Message` class knows about `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder` map and I can use this map to accurately define the size by calling `getBufferCapacity` method and if is approx less than 50k then call `sendToDatabase` method?

Comment: I think I might have a solution, but I need you to confirm my understanding of what you are trying to do is correct and I'm not missing any essential parts:
- there is a queue per partition where key-value pairs are stored;
- a single thread processes each queue;
- key-value pairs are transferred in a serialized form into byte arrays of size not exceeding 50K;
- once an array is at capacity it is sent to database, and collecting bytes for a new array begins.

Comment: The whole code looks like there are some more restrictions and aspects that you did not tell. Otherwise the code is overly complicated. E.g. crating a message instance for each junk of data  simply for being able to serialize has a smell as the outcome of serialize provides the restriction on proper instantiation in the first place. This might better be served by a loop over `clientKeyBytesAndProcessBytesHolder` that build a (serialized) buffer until size limit and then flushes buffer to `sendToDatabase` until all content has been sent.

Comment: @yegodm yes that's what I am doing exactly.

Comment: @rpy I am not sure what kind of restrictions you are talking about here.. Let me know what are the things that are not clear and I will try to improve my question accordingly.

Comment: Does the code fail to work according to your expectation or are you asking for hints on improving structure of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might get cleaner code by sorting responsibilities.
Currently, `Message` class is responsible for converting DataHolder items into a serialized form. But also t is expected to ensure size restriction is fulfilled. Unfortunately, the calling method is checking the size expectations without knowing anything about the size requirements of `Message` class.

I suggest putting responsibility on sending out proper junks of data to the `Message` class and thus remove the "knowledge about the proper data junk formatting" to the `Message` class itself.

You might also have noticed that current implementation is accounting for a full header size per item, while a header is only added once per `serialize()`

Please find below a sketch of a suggested improvement. The code would need further polishing. But it is primarily intended for illustrating elementary improvements on structure and readability/maintainability.

For isolating the `sendToDatabase()` functionality from `Message` class I just added a simple interface:

```
// decoupling the sending logic from the formatting
// if external requirements suggest linking such functionality into the message class
// such interface would be unnecessary
public interface DatabaseDelivery {
    void sendToDatabase(long addres, byte[] messagePayload);
}
```

The message class is changed to dealing with junking and size restrictions. It is now `Closeable` indicating you should call `close()` finally. (So you might consider using proper constructs with current versions of java)

```
public final class Message implements Closeable {
    // or initialize it from some external source if this might change dynamically
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
    // better determine this in sync with addHeader() method
    private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;

    private final byte dataCenter;
    private final byte recordVersion;
    private final long address;
    private final long addressFrom;
    private final long addressOrigin;
    private final byte recordsPartition;
    private final byte replicated;
    private final DatabaseDelivery delivery;
    private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    private int pendingItems = 0;

    public Message(final Partition recordPartition, final DatabaseDelivery databaseDelivery) {
        this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
        this.dataCenter = Utils.CURRENT_LOCATION.get().datacenter();
        this.recordVersion = 1;
        this.replicated = 0;
        final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
        this.address = packedAddress;
        this.addressFrom = 0L;
        this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
        this.delivery = databaseDelivery;
    }

    private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
        buffer.put(dataCenter)
              .put(recordVersion)
              .putInt(items)
              .putInt(buffer.capacity())
              .putLong(address)
              .putLong(addressFrom)
              .putLong(addressOrigin)
              .put(recordsPartition)
              .put(replicated);
    }

    private void sendData() {
        if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
            // no data to be sent
            //Properties: itemBuffer serialized size == 0
            return;
        }
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
        addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
        itembuffer.flip();
        buffer.put(itemBuffer);
        delivery.sendToDatabase(address, Arrays.copyOf(buffer.array(),buffer.position());
        itemBuffer.clear();
        pendingItems = 0;
        //Properties: itemBuffer serialized size == 0                
    }

    public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
        if (key.length > 255) {
            return;
        }
        if (data.length > 255) {
            return;
        }
        final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
        final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

        final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
        final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
        //Properties: itemBuffer serialized size < MAX
        if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE-HEADER_SIZE)) {
            sendData();
        }
        if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE-HEADER_SIZE)) {
            //XXX Use exception that is appropriate for your application
            //XXX You might add sizes involved for ease of analysis
            throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
        }
        //Properties: itemBuffer size (old+new or new) < MAX 

        final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
        final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
        // data layout
        itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength).put(data);
        pendingItems++ ;
```

//Properties: itemBuffer size < MAX
        }

```
    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (pendingItems > 0) {
            sendData();
        }
    }
```

Finally your calling code will mutate to:

```
private void validateAndSend(final Partition partition) {
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);

    // the instance providing sendToDatabase() method
    // just for cutting off details external to the discussion
    final DatabaseDelivery delivery = this;
    final Message message = new Message(partition, this);

    DataHolder dataHolder;
    while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null) {
        // XXX: why is client key using explicit encoding while process bytes is not?
        message.addAndSendJunked(dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), dataHolder.getProcessBytes());
    }
    message.close();
}
```

Please note that I added some markers (`XXX`) at places that might need attention. (Those, however, could be explained from information external to what has been provided)

There are some more details that could be considered.
E.g. I'm not convinced that using `ByteBuffer` is a proper collection for the given use case (at most places).

Edit:
With respect to testing, due to the small size of the code, you might consider applying formal verification (at least partially). This is similar to what modern compilers due with static code analysis: You walk through your code (with paper and pencil) and derive properties that hold at that very place. I added comments to the code above (marked `//Properties`) for illustrating what you might get doing so. (Mind: this is a simple illustration, and definitely would need more properties to be derived and done for each statement). I just did some minimal attributions for resulting buffer size. (using `MAX' as placeholder for the maximum acceptable size of the item part of the final buffer, aka`MAX_SIZE-HEADER_SIZE`).

Of course, may people will (correctly) suggest writing tests for the critical cases. That would be whitebox tests in that case. testing for proper functionality of the code at the corner cases of the (known) implementation. You would, also need to have blackbox tests testing behavior of your code with respect to a specification.

And also you might add runtime checks for ensuring proper behavior at critical parts. E.g. when doing `sendToDatabase()` you could check for maximum size requirement. However, such testing would need suitable input to plausibalize proper behavior. Using properties derived from code by static analysis, could provide proof of well-behavior without the final doubt of not having found the one test case that would have caused a failure.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/1667ec9968a19aa61c4a2af0e28ed9a5) for my `Processor` class which has `validateAndSend` method. Just to show you how I am using these classes. Lot of threads will call `addHolderByPartition` method concurrently to populate dataHolder corresponding to the partition and then I have a background thread in the same `Processor` class for each partition which calls `validateAndSend` method corresponding to each partition.

Comment: Now knowing my `Processor` class what are the other changes you would recommend to make this code more polish? I think my Processor code will give you an idea how my code is structured and what we can do to improve it if needed.

Comment: As I already mentioned, `ByteBuffer` is not a data structure that optimally matches with the shown code. But, maybe `sendToDatabase` is implemented in a way that profits from that choice. Another one is the header. It has the number of items in the package that happens to be known after having filled the buffer. (Likely the reason that lead to complicated code). So you could create the header and patch back in the correct value at the end.

Comment: Your `Processor` class at first the `Message` class is using lot's of (constant) values that feel like configuration data. But no solution to that aspect is being included.

Comment: Communication between data creating threads and your processors is quite straight with using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. It will allow arbitrary number (within the bounds of resources available) of threads. And your code will even work with multiple threads processing same partitions. (But then, the receiving side might need some attention. Proper use of database transactions might do, though).

Comment: And, of course, the code does as of now not deal with error cases and improper input. (e.g. it blindly enforces a 255 byte restriction on key and data parts by keeping size in a single byte and  silently ignores excesses)

Comment: yes we are sending byte array to our messaging queue which deals with byte array so that's why we need ByteBuffer.

Comment: hey, so I started testing out this code and I am seeing `java.nio.BufferOverflowException` on this line `buffer.put(itemBuffer);` in `sendData` method. For example: if you pass some key and empty data to `addAndSendJunked` method and then after that call `close` method, then in `sendData` method, it throw that exception. Any idea what could be wrong? I am in this chat [room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166779/byte-array-discussion)

Answer (score 3):

So here is my attempt (the question is probably better be addressed to the Code Review community, but anyway). It relies on some design changes to `Message` so that it becomes more like a `Builder` pattern. The buffer becomes part of the message. Its occupancy is controlled by reacting on `BufferOverflowException` exception. Once it occurs the buffer is rolled back to the last successfully added result, new message is allocated, and attempt to add the same piece of data is retried. Upon buffer completion the total number of records and the overall size are written to header, and the whole buffer is dumped to a byte array (I would probably try to avoid this extra conversion and operate on the buffer directly in `sendToDatabase`, but that's out of scope for now):

```
// TODO: structure has been adjusted for testing purposes
enum Partition
{
    A(0x1);

    private final int _partition;

    int getPartition()
    {
        return _partition;
    }

    Partition(final int partition)
    {
        _partition = partition;
    }
}

// TODO: structure has been adjusted for testing purposes
final static class DataHolder
{
    private final String _clientKey;
    private final byte[] _processBytes;

    public DataHolder(
        final String clientKey,
        final String value)
    {
        _clientKey = clientKey;
        byte[] valueBytes = value.getBytes();
        // simulate payload including extra bytes for the header
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + 8 + valueBytes.length)
                                            .order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        buffer.putInt(0).putLong(System.currentTimeMillis()).put(valueBytes);
        _processBytes = readToBytes(buffer);
    }

    String getClientKey()
    {
        return _clientKey;
    }

    byte[] getProcessBytes()
    {
        return _processBytes;
    }
}

// API has been changed to something more like the Builder pattern
final static class Message
{
    private final long address;
    private final long addressFrom;
    private final long addressOrigin;
    private final byte recordsPartition;
    private final byte replicated;
    private final ByteBuffer buffer;
    private final int writeStatsPosition;
    private int payloadCount;

    Message(Partition recordPartition, int sizeLimit)
    {
        this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
        this.replicated = 0;
        // TODO: temporarily replaced with a hard-coded constant
        long packedAddress = 123456789L;
        this.address = packedAddress;
        this.addressFrom = 0L;
        this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(sizeLimit).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        // TODO: temporarily replaced with a hard-coded constant
        byte dataCenter = 0x1;
        byte recordVersion = 1;
        buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion);
        writeStatsPosition = buffer.position();
        buffer.putInt(datacenter).putInt(recordVersion);
        buffer.putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin)
                  .put(recordsPartition).put(replicated);
    }

    /**
     * Tries to add another pair of client key and process bytes to
     * the current message. Returns true if successfully added, false -
     * if the data cannot be accommodated due to message binary size limit.
     */
    boolean add(byte[] key, byte[] value)
    {
        try
        {
            byte keyType = 0;
            byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
            short valueLength = (short) value.length;
            ByteBuffer valueAsBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(value);
            long timestamp = valueAsBuffer.capacity() > 10 ? valueAsBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
            payloadCount++;
            // remember position in the buffer to roll back to in case of overflow
            buffer.mark();
            buffer.put(keyType).put(keyLength).put(key);
            buffer.putLong(timestamp).putShort(valueLength).put(value);

            return true;
        }
        catch (BufferOverflowException e)
        {
            payloadCount--;
            buffer.reset();
            return false;
        }
    }

    byte[] serialize()
    {
        int finalPosition = buffer.position();
        // adjust the message header with the totals
        buffer.putInt(writeStatsPosition, payloadCount)
              .putInt(writeStatsPosition + 4, finalPosition);
        return readToBytes(buffer);
    }
}

static void validateAndSend(final Partition partition, final Supplier<Message> messageFactory)
    throws InterruptedException
{
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);
    Message message = messageFactory.get();
    DataHolder dataHolder;
    while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null)
    {
        final byte[] keyBytes = dataHolder.getClientKey()
                                    .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final int keyLength = keyBytes.length;
        if (keyLength > 255)
        {
            continue;
        }

        while (!message.add(keyBytes, dataHolder.getProcessBytes()))
        {
            // TODO: consider proper handling of the case when the buffer size is too small to accept even a single pair
            Preconditions.checkState(message.payloadCount > 0,
                "buffer size too small to accommodate payload");
            final byte[] serializedMessage = message.serialize();
            // TODO: makes sense to introduce a message consumer interface and call it here instead of sendToDatabase() - simplifies testing
            sendToDatabase(message.address, serializedMessage);
            message = messageFactory.get();
        }
    }
    if (message.payloadCount > 0)
    {
        byte[] serializedMessage = message.serialize();
        sendToDatabase(message.address, serializedMessage);
    }
}

static void sendToDatabase(long address, byte[] serializedMessage)
{
    // TODO: added simulating activity
    System.out.printf("Sending %d bytes to %d: %s%n",
        serializedMessage.length, address, DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(serializedMessage));
}

static byte[] readToBytes(ByteBuffer buffer)
{
    buffer.flip();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    return bytes;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException
{
    // TODO: using small value for testing - must be set to 50K in real case
    final int maxMessageSize = 80;
    final Supplier<Message> messageFactory = new Supplier<Message>()
    {
        @Override
        public Message get()
        {
            return new Message(Partition.A, maxMessageSize);
        }
    };

    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(Partition.A);
    dataHolders.add(new DataHolder("0000000001", "alpha"));
    dataHolders.add(new DataHolder("0000000002", "bravo"));
    dataHolders.add(new DataHolder("0000000003", "charlie"));
    dataHolders.add(new DataHolder("0000000004", "delta"));
    dataHolders.add(new DataHolder("0000000005", "echo"));
    dataHolders.add(new DataHolder("0000000006", "foxtrot"));

    validateAndSend(Partition.A, messageFactory);
}
```